# Symfony2 Twig Asset Base_Url is being Unpredictable?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm using a Twig loop to generate `<img src="">` for multiple images. My eventual use of this code is to take advantage of a CDN with base_url in the Framework configuration.

Below is the `Twig` code :

```
{% for key, mobj in productmedia.getImages %}
    <img src="{{ asset(path('cropImage', {'filename': mobj.getFilename }),'cdn') }}" />
{% endfor %}

{% for key, mobj in productmedia.getImages %}
  <img src="{{ asset(path('cropImageSm', {'filename': mobj.getFilename }),'cdn') }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

I would expect, at the very least for there to be some consistency in the output.. but it seems SF2 will sometimes use one base_url and sometimes not use one. Why would this be?

Below is the output.

```
<img src="http://cdn.cloudfront.net/cri/1/matt-skydiving.SH340_SW340.jpg" />
<img src="/cri/1/Swimming.SH340_SW340.jpg" />
<img src="http://cdn.cloudfront.net/cri/1/successman2.SH340_SW340.jpg" />

<img src="/cri/1/matt-skydiving.SH40_SW40.jpg" />
<img src="http://cdn.cloudfront.net/cri/1/Swimming.SH40_SW40.jpg" />
<img src="http://cdn.cloudfront.net/cri/1/successman2.SH40_SW40.jpg" />
```

As you can see in the first loop.. some inherit the base_url.. and some don't.. I've cleared all cache.. done all the general debugging steps.. It doesn't make sense why this isn't consistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can switch to the `url` twig function, it's the same as `path` but this one will always return an absolute url:

```
url('cropImageSm', {'filename': mobj.getFilename })
```

Further Reference:

`Asset()` will use the host supplied in the config.yml

```
framework:
    templating:
        packages:
            {althostname}:
                base_urls:  { http: ["http://www.domain2.com"], ssl: "/"] }
```

So `{{ asset(path('route1', {'page': 1 }),'althostname') }}` would output.. `http://www.domain2.com/route1/page/1`

Comment: Thank you Carlosz! There's a reason I want to use `path()` over `url()`. Url() does give you an absolute url and Path() will get you the relative url.. But when you use the asset() function, you can dynamically insert base_urls specified in the framework portion of your configuration.yml. I found out my problem was I was missing a **%** in my configuration file. After I added the missing **%** my results were what I expected.